# Custom Google Map marker images not showing up

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have the following code, everything works, only the markers are not showing.  I have a field in MySQL called "marker" that contains logo_1.png and I have tried quotes, full path to logo etc...., any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function initMap() {
       var myLatLng = {lat: 27.243368, lng: -80.829570};
        var opts = {
        tilt:0,
        streetViewControl: false,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.2437, -80.8324),
        zoom: 14
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);
    map.setMapTypeId('roadmap');
    map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, maptiler);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Sample Title'
  });

}


// Display custom map in tiles

var map;
var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
    new google.maps.LatLng(27.137066, -80.942569),
    new google.maps.LatLng(27.426763, -80.696534));
// var mapMinZoom = 10;
// var mapMaxZoom = 14;
var mapMinZoom = 0;
var mapMaxZoom = 75;
var maptiler = new google.maps.ImageMapType({
    getTileUrl: function(coord, zoom) { 
        var proj = map.getProjection();
        var z2 = Math.pow(2, zoom);
        var tileXSize = 256 / z2;
        var tileYSize = 256 / z2;
        var tileBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
            proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(coord.x * tileXSize, (coord.y + 1) * tileYSize)),
            proj.fromPointToLatLng(new google.maps.Point((coord.x + 1) * tileXSize, coord.y * tileYSize))
        );
        var y = coord.y;
        var x = coord.x >= 0 ? coord.x : z2 + coord.x;
        if (mapBounds.intersects(tileBounds) && (mapMinZoom <= zoom) && (zoom <= mapMaxZoom))
            return zoom + "/" + x + "/" + y + ".png";
        else
            return "http://www.maptiler.org/img/none.png";
    },
    tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
    isPng: true,

    opacity: 1.0

});

// End display custom map in

   //--------------------- Sample code written by vIr ------------
    var $marker = new google.maps.MarkerImage($marker,
               new google.maps.Size(32, 32), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
               new google.maps.Point(16, 32));
                    var center = null;
                    var map = null;
                    var currentPopup;
                    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
                    function addMarker(lat, lng, icon, info) {
                    var image = {
                       url: icon,
                       size: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
                       origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                       anchor: new google.maps.Point(lat, lng),
                       scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    };
                    var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    bounds.extend(pt);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      position: pt,
                      marker: image,
                      map: map
                    });
                        var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                            content: info,
                            maxWidth: 640
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
                            if (currentPopup != null) {
                                currentPopup.close();
                                currentPopup = null;
                            }
                            popup.open(map, marker);
                            currentPopup = popup;
                        });
                        google.maps.event.addListener(popup, "closeclick", function() {
                            map.panTo(center);
                            currentPopup = null;
                        });
                    }           
                    function initMapMarkers() {
                        var myLatLng = {lat: 27.243368, lng: -80.829570};
                        var opts = {
                        tilt:0,
                        streetViewControl: false,
                        center: new google.maps.LatLng(27.2437, -80.8324),
                        //zoom: 14
                        zoom: 7
                          };
                        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), opts);
                        map.setMapTypeId('roadmap');
                        map.overlayMapTypes.insertAt(0, maptiler);

     <?php

     $query = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM my_table")or die(mysql_error());

         while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {

    $logo = $row['logo'];
    $company = $row['company'];
    $lat = $row['lat'];
    $lon = $row['lon'];
    $marker = $row['marker'];
    $desc = $row['desc'];

        echo("addMarker(" . $lat . "," . $lon . ",'" . $marker. "'," . "'<b>" . $logo . "</b><b>" . $company ."<br />$desc' );\n");
   }
  ?>
   center = bounds.getCenter();
   map.fitBounds(bounds);

   }
   </script>

  </head>
<body onload="initMapMarkers()">
<div id="footer">Generated with <a href="http://www.maptiler.com/">MapTiler</a></div>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just checking the basics, is the 'logo_1.png' saved and accessible by the page? Have you tried hardcoding the image and getting that to work before pulling it in from the db?

Comment: Yes, logo_1.png is in same folder as all other site files.  I did try hard code and can't make it appear.  I can point to the url of the logo and it is there, just missing something in echo code about markers I guess. Echo code spits out this:
addMarker(27.1925, -80.8395, "logo_1.png", '<b><img src="companylogo.png"></b><b>Some Company<br />');

Comment: Also, companylogo.png appears fine in pop up window and is also in same folder as all site files.

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function initMap() {
        var uluru = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 4,
            center: uluru
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: uluru,
            map: map,
            image: 'icon.png'
        });
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #map {
            height: 400px;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
<div id="map"></div>

<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Your `addMarker` method takes a 3 parameters but your `echo` statement passes in 4. Also, the 3rd parameter is listed as `info` so change your `$marker: $marker` to `marker: info` removing the leading `$`

You also need to convert the `icon` name to a object and pass that into the `Marker`.

```
function addMarker(lat, lng, icon, info) {
  var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  bounds.extend(pt);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: pt,
    icon: icon
    map: map
  })
```

and then change your popup to have the correct information from the 4th parameter.

```
 var popup = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
     content: info,
     maxWidth: 640
 });
```

Something else, is that your PHP `echo` line isn't actually using the variables you created.

```
 $logo = $row['logo'];
 $company = $row['company'];
 $lat = $row['lat'];
 $lon = $row['lon'];
 $marker = $row['marker'];
 $desc = $row['desc'];

 echo("addMarker(" . $lat . "," . $lon . ",'" . $marker. "'," . "'<b>" . $logo . "</b><b>" . $company ."<br />$desc' );\n");
```

This will actually insert the values into the `echo` string to be used by your method.

Comment: I made the above change, do I need to modify the echo?  I still see no markers.  echo is now:
addMarker(27.244, -80.8249, logo_1.png, '<b><img src="somelogo.png"></b><b>Some Co Name<br />');

Comment: Is this correct at the end: <body onload="addMarker()"> or should it be
<body onload="initMapMarkers()">

Thanks!

Comment: It should be `<body onload="initMapMarkers()">`

Comment: Fixed <body onload="initMapMarkers()"> I get a map with no markers still.

Comment: Updated the answer. You can't pass the icon directly into the marker. it needs to be an object.

Comment: I updated all of the code and pasted it above. Still no markers.  If I add quotes to "logo_1.png" I get 1 marker that is just the standard Google marker, not the logo.

Comment: So can this icon object be added to the echo ?

Comment: you should be able to define it in your PHP script and then pass it to the addMarker function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I don't know php or javascript so I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Look at the answer above, I've added the icon object in the addMarker function as well as updated the `echo` output to actually use the variables you are pulling from the DB.

Comment: I used your echo and now I see this, but still no marker:
addMarker(27.244,-80.8249,logo_1.png,'<b><img src="somelogo.png"></b><b>Company Name<br />' );

Comment: I updated the code to add `'` around the logo. Error on my part

Comment: I fixed and now all makers show up, but only google red standard markers, echo code now spits out:
addMarker(27.244,-80.8249,'logo_1.png','<b><img src="somelogo.png"></b><b>Some Company<br />' );

Comment: try changing `$marker = $row['marker'];` to `$marker = './logo_1.png';` and see what you get.

Comment: same thing, only google markers show.  I have tried the entire path to logo_1.png, adding quotes, removing quotes, single quotes etc...

Comment: With all the other changes, check the `addMarker` function again and make the suggested changes. Basically removing the `icon` variable and assigning the `icon` parameter `marker: icon`

Comment: Sorry it should be `image: icon`

Comment: I pasted the most current code up top.  I changed "marker: icon" in addMarker, but all markers disappeared after that.